# Find maximum absolute scalar value in list of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a list of tensors, with different dimensions.  I want to find the maximum absolute scalar value of all the tensors.  Trouble is, I think I need a way to do greater than or less than on tensors, but I can only find `tf.equal()`.  This is the kind of thing I'd like to do:

```
curMaxAbs = tf.Variable(-1, tf.float64)
for g in myList:
    maxG = tf.abs(tf.reduce_max(g))
    minG = tf.abs(tf.reduce_min(g))
    maxAbsG = maxG if tf.greaterThan(maxG,minG) else minG
    curMaxAbs = maxAbsG if tf.greaterThan(maxAbsG, curMaxAbs) else curMaxAbs
```

Of course there doesn't seem to be a `tf.greaterThan()` function.  Obviously this would be trivial if I could use `tf.eval()` and convert to numpy arrays but unfortunately I need to do this during construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`tf.maximum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/maximum) like this:

```
maxAbsG = tf.maximum ( maxG, minG )
```